# Eclipse pom project

Tags: eclipse, pom.xml

How can I create a project in eclipse that consists only of a pom.xml?
Something like projectFolder --> pom.xml
In netbeans there is the pomProject option, but in eclipse I can't find it.
Thank you

Comment: You can create a "General > Project" or just put a `pom.xml` into a folder not needed to be a project. Could you please explain why this is not working for you? What is your root problem (the X instead of the Y of this [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))?

Comment: I understand that I can perform the task manually, but I saw that the option exists in the Netbeans IDE.
I thought that in Eclipse it should also exist.
Thank you
All the best!